# Faking locations in iOS apps with webviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, core-location

It is possible to fake locations in iOS UIWebViews. In simulator or device.

So that when a webview goes to site that requires a location (like maps.google.com), then fake location data (and routes) can be fed to the webview.

Comment: have you tried Debug->Locations-> in the iOS Simulator. The files in there allow you to mock out locations. Have never used with testing web views.

Comment: Do you know the location of those files?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a few location files provided within XCode. When running 'iPhone Simulator', you can run the files by navigating to Debug->Locations in the menu bar. These are plist's and they contain archived objects of CLLocation objects.

They can be found in the following directory:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/Support/SimulationScenarios

Just change 6.1 to the simulator you are using